# Regex-like shell glob patterns for gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore, glob

When I compile my C++ project, many shared object files are created with extensions such as

```
.so
.so.0
.so.7
.so.0.7
```

I need to add all those to my `.gitignore` file. Were this a regex, I could use

```
\.so[\.0-9]*
```

However, [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) says that `.gitignore`

> treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for consumption by `fnmatch(3)` with the `FNM_PATHNAME` flag

I found no way to do what I want with the `fnmatch` documentations I found. Is there really no way to do this?

Comment: Use multiple lines: `*.so` `*.so.[0-9]` `*.so.[0-9].[0-9]` etc.  If revs may go into two digits you'll need even more glob patterns.  (hg has `syntax:` directives in its `.hgignore` so that you can mix regex and glob as desired; maybe someone will add something like this to git someday.)

Comment: Just keeping separate install hierarchy solves this kind of thing entirely anyway.

Comment: Of interest: https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e22a85e5c01d041434682fe75f58be94de0801b

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While the answer by @SpeakEasy can ignore `.so` files in a single step using `*.so*`, for your use case of ignoring files in formats specified, you can use two entries in your `.gitignore` for more specific ignore rule

```
*.so
*.so.[0-9]*
```

---

From [gitignore man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html)

> Each line in a gitignore file specifies a pattern.
>
> Git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for consumption by [`fnmatch`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?fnmatch%203)

The important thing to note is that the pattern is not the same as regular expressions.

Python has a module named **[fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html)**, you can use that to verify whether a particular filename matches the pattern or not.

Sample example:

```
import fnmatch
pattern = "*.so.[0-9]*"
filenames = ["a.so", "b.so.0", "b.so.11", "b.so.1.0", "b.so.1.0.12"]

for filename in filenames:
    print filename, fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, pattern)

>>> a.so False
    b.so.0 True
    b.so.11 True
    b.so.1.0 True
    b.so.1.0.12 True
```

Comment: This is not *exactly* the same (although it's probably just fine): for instance, it matches `a.so.` and `b.so...9`.

Comment: Yes, I am not an expert so I don't know who should I trust most, but I feel like @torek answer is safer and clear. Tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: @mu無 Everything that will be match by `*.so.[0-9]*.[0-9]*` will also be match by `*.so.[0-9]*`, right? How to write `*.so.someDigits.someDigits`, `someDigits` being only `any number of digits`?

Comment: @arthur.sw If you want to write `*.so.someDigits.someDigits`, `someDigits` being `any number of digits` in a single line, you will need to use pattern `*.so[.0-9]*` as I suggested earlier, which will ignore all these. But it will also ignore files of the type `*.so...`, though they won't be generated under normal flow.

Comment: @mu無 I think your pattern will match  `my.pattern.is.so.6ood`. I agree it is not a big deal.

Comment: @mu無 I will give you the bounty if you correct your answer: `*.so.[0-9]*.[0-9]*` and `*.so.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*` are useless since it is already taken into account in `.so.[0-9]*`. This means that you should  change your edit. And it would be better if the solution appears first: only those two lines `*.so` and `*.so.[0-9]*`.

Comment: arthur.sw Check the edits - I have made the changes.

Comment: Not really an answer, but apparently there's no answer, so I'll have to pick yours

Answer (score 5):

Does adding the line `*.so*` not work? Or do you need more fine control?

Comment: I wanted better control just to be safe. I'm always "discovering" new extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can accomplish it in two lines:

```
.so
.so.[0-9]*
```

Answer (score 0):

From [torek's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391327/gitignore-patterns-so-0-so-0-7-etc#comment28740893_19391327):

> Use multiple lines:
>
> ```
> *.so
> *.so.[0-9]
> *.so.[0-9].[0-9]
> ```
>
> etc.

I don't know if there is a better way...

Answer (score 0):

> Python has a module named fnmatch, you can use that to verify whether a particular filename matches the pattern or not.

Not exactly correct like @mu 無 said.

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

> For example, "/*.c" matches "cat-file.c" but not "mozilla-sha1/sha1.c".

But I tried in fnmatch:

```
>>> p = "/*.c"
>>> f = "cat-file.c"
>>> fnmatch(f, p)
False
>>> f2 = "abc/def/cat-file.c"
>>> fnmatch(f2, p)
False
>>> p2 = "*.c"
>>> fnmatch(f, p2)
True
>>> fnmatch(f2, p2)
True
```

fnmatch not match `cat-file.c` but .gitignore support.

Comment: You're right. Python's `fnmatch` doesn't treat `*` and `**` the same way `gitignore` does.