# Gitignore like file convention

Tags: java, groovy, naming-conventions, configuration-files, gitignore

I'm developing a script with (Groovy/Java) which compare two folders and generate a diff patch file in zip format. The thing now is i have to ignore some file within the iteration because they should not be included in the patch file.

#### Requirement:

Create a configuration file (like gitignore file) which list the path of ignored files in the comparison process.

#### The problem:

I like to stick at convention/codestyle guidelines but now i cannot find any reference on how should this be done (not the code, i know how to do it) in terms of:

1. the name, the extention and/or location of the file.
2. the codestyle, how files should be listed (maybe i should copy gitignore pattern).
3. Other things to consider.

I hope i've been clear and my question is within SO's topic scope.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 and 2 are addressed in [`gitignore` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore): the `.gitignore` file would be part of the source files you are scanning and would apply to files from the `.gitignore` folder and below.

It uses a [glob pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34960504/6309), like [`fnmatch`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fnmatch) does (meaning: [no regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19391327/6309)).

If it was an actual git repo, [`git check-ignore -v -- afile`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) could tell you if that file is ignored or not.

Comment: I'm using [Rational Team Concert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_Team_Concert) for source control management. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Rcordoval So you have .jazzignore files (https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.scm.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_scm_eclipse_ignore.html), not .gitignore.

Comment: Sure, but **i do** want to include that file in change sets (commits) @VonC

Comment: @Rcordoval OK, but I haven't much more on the RTC side, I am afraid.

Comment: I just want to recreate a XXXignore file. But that file should be included on the source code management software, that's all. Thanks again!